# Run an ls without getting the full path

Tags: linux, ls

I want a simple list of files in a directory that is not my current directory.  I run `ls /other/directory/*.txt` and get:

```
/other/directory/file1.txt
/other/directory/file2.txt
```

I want:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

How can I get the second list?

Comment: Can you please tell us what linux distribution you are using? Because normally, ls outputs the second list you mentioned.

Comment: just tried it, i can get only full path when I call 'ls /path/*' without asterisk it is not possible, what system || shell do you use ?

Comment: I'm using CentOS.  Also, I was simplifying the original question.  I wanted only text files from the directory.  I did not realize the `*.txt` made a difference.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`(cd /other/directory && ls)`

Comment: The parenthesis open a subshell. When used in a shell script, the prompt after execution will remain in the original directory from which the shell script was called.

Answer (score 6):

Is there some reason why you can not use `ls -1` ?

```
$ ls -1 /other/directory
file1
file2
```

EDIT:

I notice you've changed the question now - my solution won't work with your new example of `ls /other/directory/*.txt`. Use something like [khachik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493928/khachik)'s solution instead, e.g.

```
$ (cd /other/directory && ls -1 *.txt)
```

Comment: I get a different behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

`ls -1 /other/directory/*.txt |xargs basename`

- `-1` will list one file per line with just the file name (or path)
- Using a wildcard and/or giving `ls` a full path will output the full, absolute path for each file. `basename` will strip the path leaving you with just the file name.

Comment: you can use `xargs -n1 basename`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `ls /some/directory` ;do basename $i;done
```

The expression in `` gets expanded to the files, then each of them is passed to basename. Caveat: Does not work with files containing white spaces!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>1) I'm not sure this shouldn't be on superuser.com</strike>

2) ls doesn't print the full path anyway: `ls -1 /your/dir`

**Edit** The question has changed. Per Paul's comment below I am updating my answer. You can do it like this:

```
ls -1 /home/rich/*.txt | sed s/^.*\\/\//
```

That's a minus 1, not l, although l works too. Explanation: ls -l/-1 writes out the file names with the stuff you don't want. Each line is piped through sed, which here is doing a substitution, as specified by the s/. A substitution takes the form:

```
s/text/replacement/
```

We are substituting everything from the beginning of the line `^` upto the last `/` (`/` is a special character so we have to escape it `\\/`) with nothing - i.e removing it, and thus leaving you with just the filename.

Comment: Not an answer - should be a comment

Comment: @Paul - how is this not an answer - yours is exactly the same!

Comment: @Richard, Paul's answer has a solution. Yours don't have any.

Comment: @Richard (1) is a comment on the question, (2) is incorrect (note the difference between `1` and `l`)

Comment: @Ruel: What? yes it does....

Comment: @Paul - ok fine, -1, -l, whatever, neither prints the full path, which is what i understood the op wanted.

Comment: fail answer copying :)

Comment: @Richard: the OP doesn't want the full path or other junk - he just wants the file names

Comment: @Paul - ok, to me that wasn't clear. He explicitly referenced the full path. But if you wanna vote me down for attempting to help, fine.

Comment: By the way, your comment 1)*I'm not sure this shouldn't be on superuser.com* is incorrect. *..this **should** be on superuser.com*

Comment: @Richard: the downvote is for failing to read the question and supplying an inappropriate answer - that's part of the purpose of the voting system, i.e. to flag good and bad answers

Comment: @Ruel, jesus give a guy a break. I was just trying to be nice.

Comment: @Paul: sure, slightly ironic then that the top voted answer is wrong.

Comment: We're just helping you pinpoint the wrong parts in your answer so you can **edit** it, supply a valid answer, and downvoters can remove the downvotes.

Comment: @Richard: I'm not sure that khachik's answer is completely wrong, as such - it just needs a `-1` flag to get the output format right.

Comment: @Paul, @Ruel - question changed, my answer updated.

Comment: @Richard: Fair enough - downvote removed. :-)

Comment: @Richard same :>

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
ls /other/directory/*.txt | xargs -n 1 basename
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want a single command without piping to accomplish a simple task, and in that case, for this you can use one of my favorite and most powerful commands in *NIX: find

For example, I would use this, if I wanted to list all directories inside a path without the preceding path:

```
find <path> -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n"
```

Let's break it down:

1. `find` - the command itself, locates all items (combination of files, directories, links, inodes, and more) in a path based on a powerful command line defined algorithm. Can be used to either simply list these items or operate upon them. Please note the ORDER OF OPTIONS IS SUPER IMPORTANT. For example, if you put the -delete option BEFORE the options that limit files to be deleted, it will DELETE EVERYTHING.
2. `<path>` - the starting location for all operations.
3. `-maxdepth 1` - Stating that from the starting path, at most, only look at items "1" deep.
4. `-mindepth 1` - Stating that from the starting path, at least, only look at items "1" deep. Together with -maxdepth, this basically tells find that I am looking at items that are specifically "1" folder deep from the starting path. This will let us operate on the contents of a folder and not the folder itself. We use this method specifically because of formatting we'll discuss later.
5. `-type d` - An optional argument that I've included to only operate on a specific item type. In this case? Directories. I could have used 'f' to only operate on files and ignore directories. Or I could use 'd,f' to select both. I like to include -type rather than omit it (which I could), because if it doesn't exist then find will operate on all items, including things like special device files, sockets, pipes, etc... of course, you may WANT that behavior.
6. `-printf "%P\n"` - The fun part. First of all, -printf operates on each found item by displaying it using 'printf-like' formatting. There are all kinds of substitutions that can be done here. Common backslash escape codes are available, hence using \n at the end to create a newline (you want this if you don't want the output to be displayed all on the same line). %P in this content outputs the trailing path member (so, the last item in the path). If you used %p instead, if would display the whole path. You can be very creative with the formatting here and I suggest looking at 'man find' for all the options of the -printf argument. As usual, encase your output in double quotes if you want shell substitutions, or single quotes if you don't require them.

Here's an example and the output:

```
# find /dev -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name i2c* -printf 'I2C Device: %P\n'
```

Output:

```
I2C Device: i2c-1
I2C Device: i2c-0
```